# Simultaneous join and update subject to a where clause on two data.tables

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to use the data.table package to update a data.table `y` depending on how columns in `y` relate to columns in `x`, where the two dataframes can be mapped together by an id.

Consider the following two data.tables:

```
x <- data.table(id=c(1,2,3),status=c(0,1,1),xend=c(2,4,7))
y <- data.table(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,3),yend=c(2,2,3,5,6,8))
setkey(x,id)
setkey(y,id)
```

Now in `y` I want to update the column `yend` when `status == 1 and yend > xend` so that `yend` becomes `xend`. Of course the following notation does not perform the operation, because I am mixing a data.table with an expression, but I thought it would help to show what I would like to do.

```
y[x[status==1] & yend>xend,yend:=xend]
```

What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Can you clearly tell us how to _join_ these two data frames together?

Answer (score 6):

Using NOCB (next observation carried forward) rolling joins:

```
# v1.9.6
y[x[status == 1L], yend := i.xend, on=c(id="id", yend="xend"), roll=-Inf]
```

Also have a look at `rollends` argument if you want to roll along the edges of each group.

There's no need to `setkey()` anymore, with the new `on=` argument implemented that allows for *adhoc* joins (as subsets).

From the next version, `on=c("id", yend="xend")` should be sufficient.

---

Note that this'll only replace the first `yend` value that is `> xend`. To replace all values, we'd need to perform a *non-equi* join, which is not yet implemented, but something we're looking into.

Until then, you can use `pmin` as suggested by @Frank, but you'll need `by=.EACHI`:

```
y[x[status == 1L], yend := pmin(yend, i.xend), on="id", by=.EACHI]
```

Comment: Is this in the development version, because it doesn't work for me on 1.9.6?

Comment: Thanks for the response! Was hoping to replace all values, rather than just the first.

Comment: @Frank, you'd need a `by=.EACHI` for that, I'd think.

Comment: How does this kind of thing get solved if there isn't a simple replacement function for the logic like `pmin`? `y[x, yend := ifelse(yend > xend, yend, xend) , by=.EACHI]` works but that `ifelse` is probably terribly slow.

Comment: @thelatemail There's a FR for assigning to subsets, like `y[x, yend[yend > xend] := xend, by=.EACHI]`, probably hard to implement, though https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/571

Comment: @Frank - looks interesting - `y[x, yend := replace(yend, !(yend > xend), xend) , by=.EACHI` might be a bit better, but nice to see it's being thought about.

Comment: thanks @thelatemail, that seemed to work for what I needed!